# No parallel processing using hive

Tags: hadoop, parallel-processing, hive

My queries in Hive are not run in parallel (just one core out of 40 at 100%), and I don't get why. I have set the options `hive.exec.parallel` to true and `hive.exec.parallel.thread.number` to 30, but that doesn't work accordint to htop. That makes my queries very long (25 minutes for creating a table of 200 000 000 entries)

I ran queries like

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mybigtable;
```

or

```sql
CREATE TABLE t STORED AS ORC 
    TBLPROPERTIES ("immutable"="true","orc.compress"="SNAPPY") 
    as SELECT x, y, z FROM tt;
```

or

```sql
SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON a.x=b.y;
```

These queries could be done by chunk, in parallel, but they are not done like that. Did I missed something ? Or is it normal ?

Answer (score 0):

This property **hive.exec.parallel** works a bit differently.
This property runs parallel query within same query, like this one:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT COL3, COL4 FROM TABLE2
```

Here the first select and second select statements are not dependent so they can be run parallely. This property helps in these kind of scenarios.

What you are asking can be achieved by running these queries using thread, and each thread opens a JDBC connection.

Hopes it helps...!!!

Comment: I expressed myself poorly, I didn't want to run these three queries at the same time, it is just some examples of queries I run. Tanks for the example, I will test it, but I don't need UNION frequently, so I am not sure I will be able to use it.